# Can't fire DC Thunder Missile Launcher from Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, usb, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have recently purchased a Dream Cheeky Thunder Missile Launcher and I wish to control it from my raspberry pi.

Using the code from retaliation (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codedance/Retaliation/master/retaliation.py)
I have managed to write a small Python script to send commands to the Thunder. Movement commands and the "stop" command work fine and actually move or stop the thunder. However when I send the fire command "0x10" the launcher does not fire and the connection to it is terminated.

I am using the standard raspbian os. Has anybody else experienced this issue and if so, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a powered hub or directly plugging the Thunder into the pi? I had the same issue and found out the pi wasn't putting out enough power on its own to shoot the darts. I got a powered usb hub and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer here ...

The Pi does not deliver enough current out of the box. You can however add `max_usb_current=1` to `/boot/config.txt` and reboot to make it deliver enough current for the  Dream Cheeky Thunder Missile Launcher (tested on Raspberry Pi 2). Make sure you have a big enough power supply.

Check settings with `vcgencmd get_config int`.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27708/is-setting-max-usb-current-1-to-give-more-power-to-usb-devices-a-bad-idea and https://github.com/martisak/martisak.github.io